# How to have angular 12 component wait for service to return api call

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am building a function that makes an API call after inputs are provided by the user on the HTML via dropdowns, once selected they trigger an API call on my service via the component, but my component is not waiting for the service to return before executing the rest of my function

API call from service.ts:

```
      this.fullSnapData =  await new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        this.apiService.GetSnapshotData(SnapShotData)
        .subscribe((data) =>{
          console.log(data);
          const fullSnapData = data
          console.log("fetched from db ", fullSnapData)
          this.fullSnapData= fullSnapData
          resolve(data)
        })
      })
      console.log("fullSnapData ", this.fullSnapData)
      return this.fullSnapData
```

Component.ts calling service is just done with:

```
let graphServiceData = this.service.getGraphServiceData(selectedBranch, timeVariable, timeScopes)
```

I assume I'm missing something in my component.ts to actually make it wait for the promise on the controller to end

Comment: You really want to read up on how Observables work. You don’t need to Promise. Also, you’re actually replacing your Promise with the data the observable returns..? Sorry my friend, this is a bit of a mess. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Display the data you get back?

Comment: I need to process the data that comes back, then display it in kendo charts

Comment: @amanill please read online about the recommended practices. Here is a blog with a simple implementation of data through observable: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-data-services-using-observable/

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to chain observables together. Here's a good article / example with links for you to read up on at the end:

https://angularlovefest.com/index.php/2022/08/02/avoiding-nested-subscriptions-in-angular/